# Nuget Packages.config change - does not force csproj update

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I've got problem with version of dependency that I set manually.
Note: I use **Automatic restore** within Visual Studio.
When I set Version="1.3.12.5" for my dependency in packages.config I expect that restore will install package and it will be referenced in next build I trigger. But it is not true. Package is installed and placed in packages directory but build does not use this downloaded packages (as csproj is not changed automatically).

Do you know possible scenarios to workaround this problem?

I tried to use Proget Client Tools but it turned out that it is not possible to use local directory feed with this. I need local and remote feeds support also, so it is additional requirement.

So, paraphrasing my question is...
How to easily change referenced version of package without touching csproj? (which is hard to edit in visual studio) Editing version twice (one in packages.config, two in csproj) is also an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Remember Package Restore simply downloads the package to the `packages` folder. It does not update project references as NuGet expects that the package had previously been installed. It's simply downloading the missing package files.

Package Restore is not a replacement for `Install-Package`. You can specify a specific version when installing. This will add the project references properly.